# How to remove proxy set in the office when working at home?

Tags: 14.04, proxy

I have proxy set in in my office laptop for work at office. I am trying to connect to wireless at home but it is not letting me do this. I tried steps in the link below without any succes. http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-configure-ubuntu-desktop-to-use-your-proxy-server.html

I am able to change the firefox setting and it is working perfect.

When doing apt-get through terminal it tries to go through proxy. I see that the  echo $http_proxy still have the proxy address.

I tried following:

cat  /etc/apt/apt.conf This file does not contain anything. gedit /etc/bash.bashrc has no mention of proxy.

I set the network proxy none, but nothing happened.

Wrote acquire::http:: proxy "false"; in /etc/apt/apt.conf, I get this acquire::http:: proxy "false";

What is wrong with my settings? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have `http_proxy` set either as a system-wide setting (either in `/etc/profile` or in `/etc/bash.bashrc`) or as your private setting (in `~/profile`, `~/bashrc` or wherever your sysadmin decided to put it).

You can get-rid of that per bash session using `unset`:

```
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
```

Or you disable it permanently when you locate where exactly it is being set.